# Android - Parcel for persistent storage

Tags: android, serialization

I'm interested in using parcelable for persistent storage in an android application that would write thousands of custom objects (comprised of string) to internal memory (because it's so much faster -  [this article says 2x faster](https://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/parcelable-vs-java-serialization-in-android-app-development) or [another article says says 10x faster](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/) ).

> "This class (and the corresponding Parcelable API for placing arbitrary objects into a Parcel) is designed as a high-performance IPC transport. As such, it is not appropriate to place any Parcel data in to persistent storage: changes in the underlying implementation of any of the data in the Parcel can render older data unreadable."

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html

> "changes in the underlying implementation of any of the data in the Parcel can render older data unreadable"

This line in particular, can someone explain what this means in detail?

Are the docs saying that the implementation of something at the level of "String" changes or rather in one of the custom classes that I am parcelling?

If I am going to be sticking with one implementation (aka storing thousands of an object comprised of 4 strings wrapped), it seems parcelable is the way to go for speed of reading thousands/tens of thousands of objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are the docs saying that the implementation of something at the level of "String" changes or rather in one of the custom classes that I am parcelling?

It could be changes in:

- One of your custom classes
- One of the framework classes that happens to be `Parcelable` that you elect to include in your `Parcelable` (e.g., `Bundle`, `Intent`, or any of [~300 others](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html))

> If I am going to be sticking with one implementation

You have no means of predicting the future. Your data model may need to change.

> it seems parcelable is the way to go for speed of reading thousands/tens of thousands of objects

No.